# how can I repeat a substitution in vim an arbitrary number of times?

Tags: regex, vim

By way of example, I really wish that the following vim substitution command would replace each and every multiple of four leading spaces with a tab in one swell foop

```
:%s/\v^(\t*) {4}/\1\t/g
```

But I still have to hammer on @: repeatedly until I get "pattern not found".  Is there an elegant way to specify "repeat until pattern not found" on the substitution command?  NOTE: I am *NOT* looking for an an answer that involves using retab -- I want a general purpose solution that is not specific to the pattern (and preferably does not involve writing any kind of script) -- a one-liner that I can rattle off using muscle memory.

Comment: Your substitution should be performed for every match in your current buffer (because of the `%` range). What is the output of `:verbose set gdefault?`?`

Comment: the output is gdefault

Comment: I think the way the g flag operates is to only scan forward, not rescan the whole line, and I think that the ^ anchor means it would have to rescan the whole line (I hoped that \zs would have prevented that but it makes no difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have anchored you substitution with `^`. Because of how Vim does substitution's it will look for the next match from the end of the last match. Use a look-behind instead:

```
:%s/\v(^\s*)@<= {4}/\t/g
```

For more help see:

```
:h /\@<=
```

Comment: Please make sure you `'gdefault'` is disabled. See the value via `:verbose set gdefault?`. Alternatively if you want `'gdefault'` then remove the `g` flag. See `:h 'gdefault'` for more information.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that contrary to the regex in my pattern, which must accommodate the presence of the replacement in order for successive applications of the substitution to succeed, the regex using a look-behind should only account for the original, as each scan will be applied to the original line.

Answer (score 2):

While not necessarily *elegant*, it is possible to precede <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> with a *count*. For instance:

<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>

Comment: It's important to note, that the count does not need to actually match the real count, because this will automatically stop when it encounters an error (e.g. "pattern not found").

Comment: This is a useful piece of information, and I did upvote it, but it doesn't answer the "spirit" of my question the way that Peter Rincker's does.